# Python: Placeholder variables in text file

Tags: python, string, file

I have a text file called `help.txt` which will be read and the contents printed out. I need the file to contain variable placeholders where the variable value will be substituted in, eg: `'I have 3 variables: {one}, {two} and {three}'`

If this was just a string hard-coded in the python file I can treat it as an f string but I am unsure how to do this in an external file.

I want the text to be in another file so that I can easily change it whenever I need to. Only I will have access to both the code and the text file.

Comment: Hi.. Welcome to SO, please include the code you have tried so far along with sample input & expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you could just check the file as you read it in for these placeholders and replace them with your variable. Given 'FileContents' is the string you used to read in your file and 'variable' is the variable to replace it with, just use `FileContents.replace("{one}", variable)`

Comment: Thanks, works great. Should have thought of this lol. I used a dictionary to store all of the placeholders and the variables they represent and then just ran it through a for loop and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are effectively syntactic sugar for `str.format` with some fancy processing of the namespaces. You can achieve the same effect using `str.format` on the contents of the file. The advantage of doing that over `str.replace` is that you have access to the full power of the string formatting mini-language.

I would recommend storing all the legal replacements into a dictionary rather than attempting to use `globals` or `locals`. This is not only safer, but easier to maintain, since you can easily load the variables from a file that way:

```
variables = {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 'b',
    'three': ...,
}
```

Printing the file is now trivial:

```
with open('help.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.format(**variables), end= '')
```